# Generate all combinations of items with two values in Julia?

Tags: julia, combinations, combinatorics

I have `m` items. Each item is a pair of two values. For example, for `m=4`, I have the matrix:

```
julia> valid_pairs = [0 1;
                      1 2;
                      1 2;
                      2 3];
```

I would like to generate all combinations of the four items where each item `i` can take only the values in `valid_pairs[i, :]`. Based on the previous example, I would like to have:

```
julia> all_combs
4x16 Array{Int,2}
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
 1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2
 1  1  2  2  1  1  2  2  1  1  2  2  1  1  2  2
 2  3  2  3  2  3  2  3  2  3  2  3  2  3  2  3
```

I feel like this can be done easily using `Combinatorics.jl`.

Though I used `Combinatorics.jl`, what I did was the following:

```
using Combinatorics

m = 4
combs = combinations(1:m) |> collect
L = length(combs)
all_combs = zeros(Int, m, L+1)
for j in 1:L
    for i in 1:m
        if !in(i, combs[j])
             all_combs[i, j] = valid_pairs[i, 1]
         else
             all_combs[i, j] = valid_pairs[i, 2]
         end
    end
end
all_combs[:, end] = valid_pairs[:, 1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the same order, but

```
julia> [collect(x) for x in Iterators.product(eachrow(valid_pairs)...)]
2×2×2×2 Array{Array{Int64,1},4}:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
 [0, 1, 1, 2]  [0, 2, 1, 2]
 [1, 1, 1, 2]  [1, 2, 1, 2]

[:, :, 2, 1] =
 [0, 1, 2, 2]  [0, 2, 2, 2]
 [1, 1, 2, 2]  [1, 2, 2, 2]

[:, :, 1, 2] =
 [0, 1, 1, 3]  [0, 2, 1, 3]
 [1, 1, 1, 3]  [1, 2, 1, 3]

[:, :, 2, 2] =
 [0, 1, 2, 3]  [0, 2, 2, 3]
 [1, 1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, 2, 3]
```

should do. If you really want a matrix (2D array), then you can `hcat` the previous answer, or directly do

```
julia> reduce(hcat, collect(x) for x in Iterators.product(eachrow(valid_pairs)...))
4×16 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1
 1  1  2  2  1  1  2  2  1  1  2  2  1  1  2  2
 1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2
 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
```

---

EDIT: side note, I would define the pairs as tuples to clarify what's happening, so something like

```
valid_pairs = [(0,1), (1,2), (1,2), (2,3)]
```

and I would not create the 2D (or 4D, or m-D) array, but, instead, do

```
comb_pairs = Iterators.product(valid_pairs...)
```

which then gives you a *lazy* version of all the pair combinations, so that you can iterate on it without actually creating it first, which should be more efficient (and looks cleaner) I think.